# Is there a way put a timestamp in the file header automatically when saving in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, timestamp, save

I am a PHP developer using Eclipse PDT. I would like a timestamp put automatically in my file headers whenever I save the file. Maybe as a replacement of a variable. Let's say I use this header in a file:

```
/**
 * ${filename}
 * ${timestamp}
 */
```

When I save the file I would this to be replaced with:

```
/**
 * Myfile.php
 * 4/20/2010 19:04
 */
```

It would also be ok if there is a macro that would add a line at the very beginning of the file just containing a timestamp.

Anybody with an idea?

Regards,
George

Answer (score 0):

There is none natively proposed by Eclipse (or [Eclipse PDT](https://www.eclipse.org/pdt/)), but you could add a language-agnostic plugin like **[AnyEdit tools](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/index.html)**, which proposes "on save" actions:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gmxhome.de](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/images/anyedit_prefs2.png))</sub>

Since none of those actions are the one you are looking for, you can have a [look at the source code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/anyedittools/source) and see how to extend those "On Save" actions to include what you are after.